Blueberry growth from seed
Month ago i started to grow blueberries from seeds (They came from the supermarket).
After a (very) long time, five have sprouted and now they've got some leaves but i've got some concerns at this point.

The seeds took a long time to sprout (approximatly 2-3 months) but then they rapidly grew and now it seams that they stop growing. Is it normal ?

Some leaves dried out and felt. What can be the cause of it ?

Some leaves are turning reddish. Is it normal ?

One of my "plant" got a huge shoot with bigger leaves and i don't know why it is the only one. Plus, it has some brown stains on, the stem. What can be the cause of it ?


As they're still young, i keep them in a little pot with a mix of peat moss / potting soil / perlite. I cutted over plants (looked like fern but i am not sure) that started to grow so their are some waste on the ground.
Bellow are some images:




Thanks for your help.

Where on planet? What sort of light do they get (looks dim in pictures?) Is the soil mix sufficiently acid for blueberries?

Are they indoors?

Peat moss - potting soil - perlite does not sound like much, if any, attention has been paid to the acidity of the soil. Blueberries like VERY acid soils, (pH 4.5-5.0) and regular potting soil with some extra peat moss is not going to get there (unless it's more than half the mix, perhaps.)
The size of pot to size and number of plants does not look good if you want more growth.
Blueberries also like full sun, which it does not appear they are getting.
